# python np.array value change

Tags: python, numpy

I'm confused as to why the following two `print(an_array)` statements gives two different results.

Although `b_slice` is explicitly defined as a `np.array` during
assignment,both `a_slice` and `b_slice` are of the same type using `type` command.Yet `a-slice` will change the value of `an_array` while `b_slice` will not. If someone could point me to the explanation I would greatly appreciate it.

```
an_array = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
a_slice = an_array[:2, 1:3]
print(type(a_slice)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(b_slice)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
b_slice = np.array(an_array[:2, 1:3]
b_slice[0,0] = 2000
print(an_array) # returns no change to an_array

[[1  2  3  4]
 [5  6  7  8]
 [9 10 11 12]]

a_slice[0,0] = 2000
print(an_array) # shows the change from the number 2 to the number 2000

[[1 2000 3  4]
 [5 6    7  8]
 [9 10  11 12]
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you explicitly* make a copy by calling the `np.array` constructor:

```
b_slice = np.array(an_array[:2, 1:3])
```

Whereas:

```
a_slice = an_array[:2, 1:3]
```

Is the result of a slice, which in `numpy` [create *views*](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html#Slice-views) instead of shallow copies, unlike vanilla lists.

**Note** * as @hpaulj points out, the [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) constructor takes a `copy` argument, which defaults to `True`.

Comment: `np.array` takes a `copy` parameter, which by default is `True`.

Comment: @hpaulj good point. I'll add the information to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand now. You have been a great help.